# Database storage: Why is Pipeline better than Feed Export?

Tags: python, database, export, scrapy, pipeline

This is a question about [scrapy](http://scrapy.org).

When storing items in a database, why is conventional to implement via a pipeline rather than the Feed Export mechanism?

[Feed Exports - Output your scraped data using different formats and storages](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exports)

> One of the most frequently required features when implementing
>   scrapers is being able to store the scraped data properly

[Item Pipeline - Post-process and store your scraped data](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline)

> Typical use for item pipelines are... storing the scraped item in a database

What's the difference, pros/cons between the two, and (why) is the pipeline more suitable?

Thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a tooooo late answer. But I just spent a whole afternoon and an evening trying to understand the difference between *item pipeline* and *feed export* which is poorly documented. And I think it would be helpful to someone who is still confused.

*TL;DR:*
FeedExport is designed for exporting items as files. It is totally not suitable for database storage.

Feed export is implemented as an extension to scrapy in `scrapy.extensions.feedexport`. In this way, just like other extensions in scrapy, it is in-turn implemented by register callback functions to some scrapy signals (`open_spider`, `close_spider` and `item_scraped`) so that it can take necessary steps to store items.

When `open_spider`, `FeedExporter` (the actual extension class) initializes feed storages and item exporters. The concrete steps involve getting a file-like object which is usually a temporary file from a `FeedStroage` and pass it to an `ItemExporter`. When `item_scraped`, `FeedExporter` simply calls a pre-initialized `ItemExporter` object to `export_item`. When `close_spider`, `FeedExporter` call `store` method on the previous `FeedStorage` object to write the file to filesystem, upload to a remote FTP server, upload to S3 storage, etc.

There is a collection of built-in item exporters and storages. But as you may notice from the above text, `FeedExporter` is by design tightly coupled with file storage. When using databases, the usual way to store items is to insert it into databases as soon as it is scraped (or possibly you may want some buffers).

Therefore, the proper way to use a database storage seems to be writing your own `FeedExporter`. You can achieve it by register callbacks to scrapy signals. But it is not necessary, using item pipeline is more straightforward and does not require awareness of such implementation details.

Comment: Well, the proper way to use database storage could also be to trigger notifications from S3 to Lambda to format your default FeedExporter format and sending it to your database from there.

In my opinion, the advantage of the above would be persisting all the pre-processed scraped data. Not exposing your endpoint and api_key to your scraping service (like Scrapinghub). Increased flexibility for error handling while posting data to your own service or database.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i understand:

Pipeline are a universal solution - you make the db connection, you know the db structure, you check for duplicates - you have control over all the process of storing the scraped items.

The exporters are predefined ways of storing scraped data. [Quote](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters):

> If you are in a hurry, and just want to use an Item Exporter to output
>   scraped data see the Feed exports.

Answer (score 0):

Feed Export is useful if you can use the default formats. If you need a custom format, you have to write a Custom Exporter, which is more work than simply storing the data in your pipeline.